# google app engine cron job and logging failed to run

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, cron, stackdriver

I am facing an issue in which I have configured a cron job in google app engine and it is successfully deployed but unfortunately it failed to run. The screenshot below show the configured cron job with the status

[image]

Another issue is when I click on view in the log column it shows as follows:

[image]

Can anyone please guide me how can I debug the issue of the cron not running in this case.

Thanks,

Comment: cron config? handler code?

Comment: You can also try to trigger the job manually, using a GET request for the respective URL, see what happens...

Comment: Now I am able to view the logs and the following error is appearing in the logs

Request failed because URL requires user login. For requests invoked within App Engine (offline requests like Task Queue, or webhooks like XMPP and Incoming Mail), the URL must require admin login (or no login)

Can you guide me regarding to this error

Comment: That referes to the auth options configured in your app for the cron job's URL: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication